# Override hardware volume buttons at lock-screen (device is awake)

Tags: java, android, keyevent

I have searched for a solution on SO, and while this might seem to be a duplicate, most of the similar questions are asking how to detect hardware volume keys when the screen is **Off**. I have found suggestions of using a Broadcast Receiver but not a full explanation.

I have successfully overridden [dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#dispatchKeyEvent(android.view.KeyEvent)) method in my `Activity`. However, when the screen is locked (but phone is awake) these keys do not respond.  Can someone please point me in the right direction to where I can detect these presses when the screen is **On** but still locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found `WindowManager.LayoutParams` [FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams#FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED), which although depreciated in API 27, works well and does what I really want on my API 26 device. I put the code in my Activity's `onCreate(...` method right before `setContentView(...`.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1) {
    this.setShowWhenLocked(true);
} else {
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
}
```